# How should one interpret the Haskell character '\250'

Tags: haskell, escaping, ascii

I am trying to understand how escapes work in Haskell.

`head "\250\218"`
returns
`'\250'`

So Haskell thinks \250 is a character. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Haskell escapes are not terribly different from other programming languages. `"\123"` is a representation of Unicode codepoint 123 (decimal). `"\x3f"` is codepoint 0x3f (hexadecimal). And so on. What confuses you, exactly?

Comment: I ran into some test code that appeared to treat \250 as four characters but treated \ACK as a character, so I wasnt sure if unicode was somehow treated differently than ASCII escape.

Answer (score 8):

The string `"\250\218"` consists of two numeric escapes, each denoting one character, with the character codes given in decimal.  Applying `head` returns the first of these, printed `'\250'`.  If you apply `Data.Char.ord` to this, you will see that it has numeric code 250 (decimal).  You can make a similar character using `Data.Char.chr`.

As you can see below, printing the characters with these codes results in accented letters according to Unicode.

Using GHCi:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> head "\250\218"
'\250'
Prelude> Data.Char.ord (head "\250\218")
250
Prelude> Data.Char.chr 251
'\251'
Prelude> putStrLn "\250\218"
úÚ
Prelude>
```

For more information:

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/characters-strings-and-escaping-rules.html#id689632

Answer (score 6):

`'\250'` is whatever Unicode character has code point (decimal) 250, in this case LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE (ú).